# Mongodb ISODate format comparison not working in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb record like `"estdate" : "2016-06-14T06:49:00.000Z"`
 I am writing the following php code to query the time

```
$from=$start = new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-04-11 00:00:00'));
 $to=new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-06-18 00:00:00'));
 $filterpatient = array("order.patientinfo.order_id" => $ordertext,"order.orderitem.estdate" => array('$gte' =>$from, '$lte' => $to));
 $cursor = $collection->find($filterpatient)->sort(array('_id'=>-1));
```

But this is giving no result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongodb driver, this might be helpful for you.

$starttime = strtotime("2016-04-11 00:00:00");
$utcstartdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($starttime);

Now use the $utcstartdatetime in your query for time.

Comment: The Idea is good but the resulte is not, `strtotime` returns the number of seconds (aka UNIX timestamp) when `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime` takes milliseconds, just multiply by 1000